# Regex to match with and without street type

Tags: regex

My regex currently searches an address for 4 parts. Number, street name, street type, and a unit match. The issue I'm having is when a street type match isnt found. How can I modify my regex to match "123 testing" while continuing to match "123 testing dr" and "123 testing ct UNT 123"

Regex:

```
(\d+).*?((?:[a-z](?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+)).*?((?:court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|road|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trail|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw)).*?((?:UNT|\#)[^\S\r\n]?\w|\w.*)?$
```

[Tester](https://regex101.com/r/h3LYzN/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "address without street type etc." to your original pattern using alternation:

```
(\d+).*?((?:[a-z](?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+)).*?
((?:court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|road|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trail|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw))
.*?((?:UNT|\#)[^\S\r\n]?\w|\w.*)?$
|
(\d+).*?((?:[a-z](?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+))$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/h3LYzN/5